# How many navigation options is "too many"?

Tags: navigation, conventions, simplicity

My website's main navigation bar looks like this:[image]

I counted, and there are 7 navigation items in total. Most websites have one navigation item on the left side of the bar with their logo on it that goes to the homepage, with 4 others next to it that go to different major parts of the website.

Do I have too many options in the navigation bar, and how can I simplify it if there are too many?

EDIT: I've considered compressing "Our Work", "Documents", and "People" into one dropdown menu titled "Our...". Will this work?

Comment: NN Group - [how many items in a navigation](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/number-items-navigation-menu/)

Comment: Is this how it looks on a mobile device? Usually that's one simple way to test whether you have too many navigation items or whether the IA needs some tweaking.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a "home" navigation item. Its still wise to allow the logo to take you back, but available data doesn't show users typically caring to "return home".

I would suggest that seven top level options is much better than hiding things in a dropdown. Combining them decreases "findability". That said, you really only have five actual navigation items. That doesn't seem excessive to me.

If you want to simplify further, there are two questions you need to answer.

1. What are the most important things for people to do on the site? (use analytics to find what users visit AND consider business priorities) If anything in that list doesn't represent a priority, remove it.
2. Can you combine content instead of navigation? For example the "About Us" content/page would be a logical place to also include "people". But you need to ensure that bios aren't a primary task for users to locate info.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the Home button. People tend to not use it, and in fact most people use the logo to go back home (see article [Are You Putting The Home button To Good Use?](https://uxmag.com/articles/are-you-putting-the-home-button-to-good-use)) after being trained to by websites like Youtube, Facebook, Google etc..

That lowers you from 7 to 6.

What about the "Our Work" and "People" options? I would make the "Our Work" button a dropdown with "People" and "About Us" options.

That lowers you from 6 to 4.

I wouldn't make a general "Our..." dropdown because it is, well, general. Keeping the dropdown button a bit more specific will make it clearer to people what it does before they have to interact with it (clicking or hovering).